# Why is my Github Actions job being skipped?

Tags: bash, yaml, github-actions, exit-code

Been trying to figure this out for a couple of days now. I have these jobs in a GitHub Actions workflow:

```
jobs:
    
  check-for-changes:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        
      - name: Install Black
        run: python -m pip install black
        
      - name: Check Black Formatting
        id: check
        continue-on-error: true
        run: |
          black black_test.py --check
          exit_code=$?
          echo "exit_code=$exit_code" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

  black-formatting:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [check-for-changes]
    if: ${{ needs.check-for-changes.outputs.exit_code == 1 }}
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        
      - name: Install Black
        run: python -m pip install black
        
      - name: Apply Black Formatting
        run: black black_test.py
```

The logic that I'm trying to build is for the `check-for-changes` job to always run first. Then, it checks whether or not a Python file needs to be formatted or not with Black. I'm capturing the exit code and saving it using an [output](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-11-github-actions-deprecating-save-state-and-set-output-commands/).

The next job, `black-formatting` should run **ONLY** if there is an exit code of `1` from the `check-for-changes` job.

I just ran it with the provided `yml` file with a file that needs to be reformatted (I checked the output of the `check-for-changes` job and there was a message stating that a file would need to be formatted and an exit code of 1) and the job was skipped? If I switch the `if: ${{ needs.check-for-changes.outputs.exit_code == 1 }}` line to `== 0`, then it continues but that shouldn't be happening. I'm not sure if I am capturing the `exit_code` properly or if there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 issues in play:

1. You need to declare the output variable at the step as well as at the job level
2. Bash will stop processing when a command returns an error.

### Declare the output variable at the job level

Your 2nd job can't access the step output without you also declaring it as a job output:

```yaml
jobs:
  check-for-changes:
    # Map a step output to a job output
    outputs:
      exit_code: ${{ steps.check.outputs.exit_code}}

    steps:
      - name: Check Black Formatting
        id: check
        run: |
          echo "exit_code=1" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

Then reference that in the 2nd job:

```yaml
jobs: 
  black-formatting:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [check-for-changes]
    if: ${{ needs.check-for-changes.outputs.exit_code == 1 }}
```

### Bash stops processing when a command returns a non-0 exit code.

Your script `black black_test.py --check` returns a non-0 exit code, bash will stop processing the rest of the script. The code to set the `exit_code` variable and the code to set the output variable are skipped, so the value of the output variable will either be `0` or  .

You can capture the exit code and continue processing, you can add `|| exit_code=$?` after the failing command:

```yaml
      - name: Check Black Formatting
        id: check
        continue-on-error: true
        run: |
          black black_test.py --check || exit_code=$?
          echo "exit_code=$exit_code" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

The `continue-on-error: true` doesn't let bash keep processing, it just doesn't cause the job to fail if anything fails in the script, even if the script is terminated half-way.

### Final script:

```yaml
jobs:
    
  check-for-changes:
    outputs:
      exit_code: ${{ steps.check.outputs.exit_code }}

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        
      - name: Install Black
        run: python -m pip install black
        
      - name: Check Black Formatting
        id: check
        run: |
          black black_test.py --check || exit_code=$?
          echo "exit_code=$exit_code" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

  black-formatting:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [check-for-changes]
    if: ${{ needs.check-for-changes.outputs.exit_code == 1 }}
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        
      - name: Install Black
        run: python -m pip install black
        
      - name: Apply Black Formatting
        run: black black_test.py
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Seems like I am still having the same issue... I applied that `outputs:  exit_code: ${{ steps.check.outputs.exit_code}}`  line and the job was still skipped. I checked the previous job's logs and there was an exit code of 1 since the file needed to be changed. Does the `outputs:` have to come after the `steps`?

Comment: Was just looking at these [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#needs-context) and that doesn't seem to be the case. I must not be capturing the exit code properly.

Comment: Just added a workflow I've ran myself an know to be working.